# Observer on class Mage_Core_Model_App end in function run

Tags: php, magento

Look `app\code\core\Mage\Core\Model\App.php`

```
public function run($params)
    {
        $options = isset($params['options']) ? $params['options'] : array();
        $this->baseInit($options);
        Mage::register('application_params', $params);

        if ($this->_cache->processRequest()) {
            $this->getResponse()->sendResponse();
        } else {
            $this->_initModules();
            $this->loadAreaPart(Mage_Core_Model_App_Area::AREA_GLOBAL, Mage_Core_Model_App_Area::PART_EVENTS);

            if ($this->_config->isLocalConfigLoaded()) {
                $scopeCode = isset($params['scope_code']) ? $params['scope_code'] : '';
                $scopeType = isset($params['scope_type']) ? $params['scope_type'] : 'store';
                $this->_initCurrentStore($scopeCode, $scopeType);
                $this->_initRequest();
                Mage_Core_Model_Resource_Setup::applyAllDataUpdates();
            }

            $this->getFrontController()->dispatch();
        }
        return $this;
    }
```

I know that to create an event / observer I need to do the following:

```
<events>
  <EVENT_TO_HOOK>
    <observers>
      <module>
        <type>singleton</type>
        <class>company_module_model_observer</class>
        <method>methodToCall</method>
      </module>
    </observers>
  </EVENT_TO_HOOK>     
</events>
```

but i dont know how to catch the event of the `run` function of the class `Mage_Core_Model_App`

what is the name of the event in order to observe this function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is not observer at this point in Magento's dispatch.  The is systems level code, and not meant to be interfered with by extension developers.  The only places you can use an observer in Magento are where you see

```
Mage::dispatchEvent('event_name' ...)
```

Comment: I wanted to make a module to get data of `getModelInstance`, `getNodeClassInstance` and `getResourceModelInstance` of the class `Mage_Core_Model_Config` , any idea how I can do this